# Change dimension of matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 4x10 table that I want to convert into 40x1 matrix. I am wondering why I am getting the error message when I try to change the dimensions? It was working on another table, so I think it may have something to do with the NaN in this particular table, but I'm not sure.

```
B="
0.2000000 0.2200000 0.2100000 0.9000000 0.2200000 0.0500000 0.2300000 0.0500000 0.1900000 0.2200000 0.3333333 0.3857143 0.4121212 0.2033898 0.3779528 0.3333333 0.4260355 0.1038961 0.1666667 0.4522613

0.1700000 0.0500000 0.1700000 0.1600000 0.1800000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.1900000 0.0500000 0.2300000 0.4372093 0.2443890 0.4000000 0.4100719 0.4575646 0.3225806 0.3843137 0.4195804 0.1986755 0.3934426

0.0500000 0.0500000 0.0500000 0.3100000 0.0500000 0.0500000 0.0500000 0.0500000 0.3900000 0.3800000 0.5714286 0.1818182 0.5263158 0.5000000 0.1111111       NaN 0.4000000 0.1818182 0.6250000 0.2105263

0.0500000 0.0500000 0.0500000 0.0500000 0.2400000 0.0500000 0.0500000 0.1700000 0.0500000 0.0500000 0.4347826 0.2222222 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2105263 0.2000000 0.2500000 0.6451613 0.1200000 0.1208054"
Y=read.table(text=B)
F1nn=Y[,11:20]
dim(F1nn)=c(40, 1)
```

```
> dim(F1nn)=c(40, 1)
Error in dim(F1nn) = c(40, 1) : 
  dims [product 40] do not match the length of object [10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to construct a `matrix`, `unlist` the `data.frame` and then simply wrap with `matrix`

```
out <-  matrix(unlist(F1nn))
dim(out)
#[1] 40  1
```

Or if we want to use `dim<-`

```
`dim<-`(unlist(F1nn), c(40, 1))
```

or convert to `matrix` (as a `matrix` is a `vector` with dim attributes)

```
`dim<-`(as.matrix(F1nn), c(40, 1))
```

---

Or if it needs to be `data.frame`

```
out <- data.frame(col1 = unlist(F1nn))
```